# Error attempting to evaluate cell containing formula of another calculation cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of formulas in it and several tabs. One of the tabs is for Input of numbers into 10 fields. Another tab is for viewing the output of calculated formulas.

Using Apache POI, I have opened the spreadsheet and input my numbers. The problem comes when I try to evaluate the spreadsheet.
I've tried

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
helper.createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

And I get an error (that nobody seems to have an answer for): `Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)] with root cause`

So I've changed to evaluating cells individually so I could find which cell has the error, so my code looks like this:

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = this.workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
for (Sheet sheet : this.workbook) {
  System.out.println("Evaluating next sheet");
  System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
  for (Row r : sheet) {
    System.out.println("Row Number:");
    System.out.println(r.getRowNum());
    for (Cell c : r) {
      if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
          System.out.println(c.getColumnIndex());
          try {
            evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              rowArray.add(r.getRowNum());
              cellArray.add(c.getColumnIndex());
            System.out.println("Skipping failed cell");
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

And I'm getting the same error as when I run evaluateAll.
By putting the little bit of debugging in there, I found that the error is coming from Cell L3, which contains formula: `=D5`. Since the evaluator goes by row:column, it evaluates everything on row 3 first before getting to 5, so L3 references a field that has not been evaluated yet, and therefore throws an error.

I tried catching the errors and storing the row and cell number in an array, then after everything in a sheet is processed, attempt to reprocess the unprocessed cells, but I still get the same result. I'm a bit perplexed why the retry didn't work.

Retry code:

```
  // try to fix any failed evaluations here
  Iterator cellItr = cellArray.iterator();
  Iterator rowItr = rowArray.iterator();

  while (cellItr.hasNext()) {
    Integer cellElement = (int) cellItr.next();
    Integer rowElement = (int) rowItr.next();

      XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowElement);
      XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellElement);

      System.out.println("Re-evaluating: " + rowElement + " : " + cellElement);
      evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
  }
}
```

The retry code gave the same result.
I tried changing the original evaluator to use evaluateInCell to change the formula to an actual number, but that didn't seem to help.

----------------- UPDATE ---------------------
I just realized that evaluateFormulaCell is deprecated in favor of evaluateFormulaCellEnum. I put all of the code into a function and ran the function multiple times and realized it's evaluating all of the cells over and over again, so I switched to using evaluateInCell and found that it only evaluates each cell once, but still can't get pass the cells mentioned.
Here is my updated code, which I have inside a function that I run 5 times:

```
for (Sheet sheet : this.workbook) {
    System.out.println("Evaluating next sheet" + sheet.getSheetName());
  for (Row r : sheet) {
    for (Cell c : r) {
      if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
          System.out.println("Cell index: " + r.getRowNum() + " - " + c.getColumnIndex());
          try {
            evaluator.evaluateInCell(c);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                evaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(c);
              } catch (Exception ee) {
                System.out.println("Skipping failed cell after 2 attempts");
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "And I get an error: Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)": A formula in the evaluation chain is missing an argument. But without having the Excel file it is hard to help here. That's why "nobody seems to have an answer for". So it would be helpful it you could provide the Excel file to download somewhere.

Comment: Btw.: Your debugging approaches seems to be not really purposeful. Try using `evaluator.setDebugEvaluationOutputForNextEval(true);` as described in [Formula Evaluation Debugging](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Formula+Evaluation+Debugging) to get the exact formula cell which fails.

Comment: My debugging approach is very purposeful. It told me exactly what formula cell failed, which is how I was able to find what and where the problem is. I'll see if I can get a spreadsheet uploaded at any point. I have someone looking at it now to see if they can get around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the debugging I have in place, I was able to see which cells in the spreadsheet were failing, so I saved the formulas from the failing cells in a text document and replaced the formulas with their values, then recompiled the code and the spreadsheet actually evaluated!

Then I went through all of the cells and put their formulas back two by two until it broke again. It turned out to be a case I already knew about, but searching a spreadsheet for is no piece of cake.

This was the formula with the issue: `=ROUNDUP('HW page'!$H$53*'HW page'!$H$54,)`
I added a 0 as the last parameter so it looks like this: `=ROUNDUP('HW assumptions'!$H$53*'HW assumptions'!$H$54,0)`, then the evaluator works.

Comment: Exactly what the error told you from begin on: `Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)`: A formula in the evaluation chain is missing an argument.

Comment: *facepalm* I should have seen that the first time. Thank you!